# How to append a file exactly at the tail of the last sentence using Sed command

Tags: linux, bash, append

I need to output a bash scripts in csv format, the output i wanted is as follow. while i need to append file named 1.2.6.2.txt right after the tail of 1.2.6.1.txt and it cannot be a next row entry, preferred to finish this using sed command.

```
#cat result/1.2.6.1.txt
1.2.6 Disable Proxy Modules,command to get result httpd -M | grep proxy_,expected result should be null
```

And:

```
#cat result/1.2.6.2.txt
" proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_connect_module (shared)
 proxy_express_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
 proxy_ftp_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)"
```

**The output i needed:**

```
1.2.6 Disable Proxy Modules,command to get result httpd -M | grep proxy_,expected result should be null,"
proxy_module (shared)
proxy_ajp_module (shared)
proxy_balancer_module (shared)
proxy_connect_module (shared)
proxy_express_module (shared)
proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
proxy_fdpass_module (shared)
proxy_ftp_module (shared)
proxy_http_module (shared)
proxy_scgi_module (shared)
proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)
"
```

Already tried this command to able to append text right after the tail of a file

## sed -e $'$s/$/:SUFFIX &/' result/1.2.6.1.txt

1.2.6 Disable Proxy Modules
command to get result httpd -M | grep proxy_
expected result should be null:SUFFIX

But when i tried the command below, the e cat result/1.2.6.2 command which suppose to add the content of 1.2.6.2.txt after the original sentence doesn't work:

```
# sed -e $'$s/$/{e cat result\/1.2.6.2.txt}/' result/1.2.6.1.txt
1.2.6 Disable Proxy Modules
command to get result httpd -M | grep proxy_
expected result should be null{e cat result/1.2.6.2.txt}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you need to escape the `/` character in `{e cat result/1.2.6.2.txt}`.
So you could run it as follows:

```
sed -e $'s/$/{e cat result\/1.2.6.2.txt}/' result/1.2.6.1.txt
```

Without using `sed`, you can simply run:

```
cat result/1.2.6.1.txt >> 1.2.6.2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your advise about the escape character, I will try it out.But unfortunately Cat couldn’t help in this case, as it will end up with a new row in csv, I will need the whole entry as one row in csv

Comment: @PokManALvinLi: Try the new answer!

Comment: I had tried the variables solution you gave me it is in one row, but actually the content of result/1.2.6.2.txt was in different row, the reason is actually the content of it is representing a csv in a single cell with different row, that's the hard part of it, and that's why i want a command in Sed to do it

Comment: By the way, I had tried to add escape character inside the sed command sed -e $'$s/$/{e cat result\/1.2.6.2.txt}/' result/1.2.6.1.txt

, but it doesn't work as expected... for the result please see my updated question above

Comment: @PokManALvinLi: Sorry, I can't understand what do you want to achieve. because the my answer gives you the result you are expecting, hat is wrong ith it?